# SKPaymentQueue Dealloc Issue When Switching Between UIViews

Tags: ios

I have the following in app purchase code.

```
- (IBAction)purchaseProduct:(id)sender
{
    SKProduct *thisProduct = [productDetailsList objectAtIndex:[sender tag]];

    if ([thisProduct.productIdentifier isEqualToString:@"demo"]) {
        SKPayment *payment = [SKPayment paymentWithProductIdentifier:@"demo"];
        [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addPayment:payment];
    }
}
```

The purchase screen is a sepearate uiview controlled by a navigation controller. The first time I load the screen and make a purchase all is fine. If however I load the screen, leave and then go back and make a purchase I get the following error:

```
*** -[FilterPurchase respondsToSelector:]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x1fd92ca0
```

After doing a break point check the error seems to occur around about this line:

```
[[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addPayment:payment];
```

Can anyone see the issue here? I am using ARC so I am a little unsure how to go about resolving the issue.

Thanks

UPDATE

Same thing is happening if I also click on the "Restore" button

```
- (IBAction)restorePurchases:(id)sender
{
[[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] restoreCompletedTransactions];
}
```

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately it is difficult to try and find the exact problem.

Comment: @11684 Using ARC with an application which heavily uses blocks or Core Foundation objects is a much bigger pain.

Comment: Yes, I can imagine. But the simplicity of the example app was the point of my comment. Summary: 'ARC does mess up even the simplest apps.' @Sulthan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To resolve this issue I have added the following to the code to remove the observer when the view is changed.

```
-(void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {

[[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] removeTransactionObserver:self];

}
```

Answer (score 1):

`[SKPayment paymentWithProductIdentifier:@"demo"];` is a decrepated function

Try using `SKPayment *payment = [SKPayment paymentWithProduct:thisProduct];`

EDIT:

the other thing your missing is a transactionOberver.

Add:

```
[[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addTransactionObeserver:self];
```

Your code will then look as follows:

```
- (IBAction)purchaseProduct:(id)sender
{
    SKProduct *thisProduct = [productDetailsList objectAtIndex:[sender tag]];

    if ([thisProduct.productIdentifier isEqualToString:@"demo"]) 
    {
        SKPayment *payment = [SKPayment paymentWithProduct:thisProduct];
        [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addTransactionObeserver:self];
        [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addPayment:payment];
    }
}
```

Comment: This has resolved the warning message but still no luck with the actual error.

Comment: The other thing you are missing besides that to my working in app purchases is a transactionobserver

Comment: I have [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addTransactionObserver:self]; in the view did load

Comment: like the other answer says, It is probably deallocated before the actual transaction happens. Add it to your code just before the addPayment: method

Comment: Just added it but unfortunately it hasn't made a difference.

Comment: Alright so it's not in the payment part of the program. What about this FilterPurchase class? What does it do in your program? And how do you use it?

Comment: Just put in an update above, it seems to be happening when I click on the restore button as well.

Comment: That doesn't answer my question tho. What about this FilterPurchase class? What does it do in your program? And how do you use it?

Comment: The Filter Purchase class is simply a UIView that is called via a Navigation Controller. The view itself has a button for restoring purchases and a table to display a list of products to buy. The user then clicks on the item and the system is updated once the IAP is made.

Comment: In that class it tries to access an object that is needed for the purchase the moment you press a button. But that object is deallocated. Recheck the manner of which you populate that tableview in there. You might have deleted the item you need before you actually used it. Try to isolate the exact purchase/restore function and remove any of the update functions you do (or think you do). The problem might lie there.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the help I think the problem is now resolved. It turned out that the transaction observer needs to be removed when leave the view. If it isn't removed then the app tries to call the old observer.

Answer (score 1):

According to the docs:

> An application should always have at least one observer of the payment
>   queue before adding payment requests.

It sounds like your SKPaymentTransactionObserver may be getting deallocated along with your IAP uiview.